# Swift Core Data Double doesn’t accept decimal numbers

Tags: swift, core-data, double, decimal

In a Swift app I have a variable with a value between 0 and 2 with a default value of 0.3

The user can change this value later. It’s a double, both the variable which I use in the app and the corresponding attribute in Core Data.

For some reason the default value in Core Data can’t be set to a decimal number. So I use a work around by setting the default to 3 and calculate things in the app, but this is error prone to my idea.

How can I set the default value of a Core Data double to decimal value?

Comment: Why does Xcode not accept a Double? Are there any error messages or issues with the UI?

Comment: No xcode does, but the attribute in a coredata entity doesn’t. 
There are no errors or issues apart from this.

Comment: Edit the `xcdatamodeld` file and you can set default values there which include decimal places.